# Entity Framework и virtual

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос. Практически во все примерах кода с использованием Entity Framework свойства классов моделирующих таблицы БД имеют модификатор `virtual`. Видел где-то что это нужно для реализации *ленивой загрузки*. Как эти две вещи связаны между собой? Или может необходимость в `virtual` состоит в чем-то еще?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё верно, для функционирования *ленивой загрузки* модификатор `virtual` необходим. Связано это с возможностью переопределения свойств как раз-таки, т.е. напрямую с возможностями `virtual`.

Например, вот [тут](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708210205/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) почитайте.